# Deserialize XML into C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, xml, windows, winforms, deserialization

I've got an XML file that is created via my Windows form to save two text fields and 2 date time pickers.

I am wondering how to "load" (preferably by asking the user where the file is) this back into my form so that it can be edited and saved again.

```
public class Values 
{
    public string task1_name { get; set;}
    public string task1_desc { get; set;}
    public DateTime task1_date { get; set;}
    public DateTime task1_time { get; set;}
}
```

Save Button on my form

```
void SavebuttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save?",
        "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Values v = new Values();
        v.task1_name = this.task1_name.Text;
        v.task1_desc = this.task1_desc.Text;
        v.task1_date = this.task1_date.Value;
        v.task1_time = this.task1_time.Value;
        SaveValues(v);  
    }
}
```

Third Part

```
public void SaveValues(Values v)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Values));
    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"E:\TheFile.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the code that generates the xml?

Comment: Done that in my original post :) thanks!

Comment: Please stop adding "Solved" to your titles. Please. This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Values v = LoadValues();
    this.task1_name.Text = v.task1_name;
    this.task1_desc.Text = v.task1_desc;
    this.task1_date.Value = v.task1_date;
    this.task1_time.Value = v.task1_time;
}

public Values LoadValues()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Values));
    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"E:\TheFile.xml"))
    {
        return (Values)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    }
}
```

I recommend to have the serializer in one variable so it won't be created each time (it's expensive to construct a new XmlSerializer)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, my code tells me that "textWriter" doesn't exist in this context though? - i've inserted the values v = loadvalues (); part into my button code and the other part below it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Do you know how to get it to pop up a dialog box to ask the user where to load/save from? I cant get my head round the control someone mentioned above :)

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but StarkOverflow if for answering specific questions, not learning. You could have googled it.

Comment: I know... but im using XML serialization and being new to coding i have no idea what i need to do. It saves it as an XML file but i'd just like it ask the user where to save it? I just presumed it would be simple but to me it doesn't look it

Comment: Check the link I commented before. It's really easy.

Comment: I can get it to create the file but not populate it with XML

Comment: Use the OpenFileDialog... http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.80).aspx

Really, you need to do some research instead of ask everything

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the xml and update the form with the parsed data. There is a file picker dialog in visual studio for the user to select a file.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("books.xml");

while (reader.Read()) 
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: Im quite new to coding. How would i parse the data? And thanks for the hint on the file picker!

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the xml into an object and use that object to reload the fields..

For that first create the xsd for that xml using xsd.exe.. Then you can create the class file using the same exe and deserialize the xml into that object using XmlSerializer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at; as my above comment im fairly new to coding. Sorry! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Well, you can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx) as well..